# How to change paragraph separation to indent within blockquote (csquotes)

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs, quoting, csquotes

I am using the package [`csquotes`](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) to generate a blockquote. `csquotes` inserts what looks like half a blank line between the paragraphs within the quote.

I would prefer to have no vertical space but an indent like new paragraphs in regular text. How can I do this?

I have prepared the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\begin{document}
\section{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer a purus vel lacus eleifend feugiat sed id eros. 
%
\blockquote{Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc congue,
\emph{here ends the first paragraph within the blockquote.}

\emph{This should be indented.} Aenean vulputate dolor id nulla  
sollicitudin quis facilisis sem ultrices. Sed congue consequat 
viverra. Suspendisse malesuada sodales viverra.}
%
Nullam eget elit vel nunc interdum accumsan. Phasellus posuere 
enim eu eros blandit viverra.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer a purus vel lacus eleifend feugiat sed id eros.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the block environment that `\blockquote` uses with `\SetBlockEnvironment`. By default it uses the `quote` environment which puts some vertical space between paragraphs. Set it to use the `quotation` environment, `\SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}`,  to get a newline and indention between paragraphs. Note that this will indent the first paragraph in the blockquote too (and it will apply to every command in `csquotes` that creates blockquotes).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quotation}% I've only added this

\begin{document}

\section{}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer a purus vel lacus eleifend feugiat sed id eros. 
%
\blockquote{Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci 
luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nunc congue,
\emph{here ends the first paragraph within the blockquote.}

\emph{This should be indented.} Aenean vulputate dolor id nulla  
sollicitudin quis facilisis sem ultrices. Sed congue consequat 
viverra. Suspendisse malesuada sodales viverra.}
%
Nullam eget elit vel nunc interdum accumsan. Phasellus posuere 
enim eu eros blandit viverra.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
Integer a purus vel lacus eleifend feugiat sed id eros.

\end{document}
```

[image: csquote's \blockquote using the quotation environment].

Comment: Thank you very much, I must have missed that in the documentation.

Answer (score 8):

You may also use the `quoting` environment of the [package](http://ctan.org/pkg/quoting) of the same name (Disclosure: I'm the package author). `quoting` will use the indentation and `parskip` of the surrounding text (i.e. it will resemble `quotation` with LaTeX's default settings), but first-line indentation is activated by adding a blank line before the environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{quoting}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\SetBlockEnvironment{quoting}

\newcommand*{\sometext}{Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This
    text should show, how a printed text will look like at this place.
    If you read this text, you will get no information.}

\begin{document}

\sometext
%
\blockquote{% First line not indented
\sometext

\sometext
}

\sometext

\blockquote{% First line indented
\sometext

\sometext
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: Unlike the `quotation` environment of the LaTeX standard classes, the `quoting` environment will also mimic changes to the paragraph indentation of normal text (e.g. done with `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}`).

Comment: Thanks (danke!), this looks even better, I am going to use your package. But I will keep N.N.'s answer as the accepted one, because yours is going one step beyond the original question.

Comment: @locktep do you know your `quoting` package (good one, thanks) is in conflict with the spanish version of the `babel` package about `\quoting` command with this error message : `Command \quoting already defined` ? You should indicate in your documentation this conflict. See the solution here (in German) : http://golatex.de/unvereinbarkeit-von-babel-und-quoting-packages-t12866.html